# C# XSD Validation Fails on Element with minOccurs="0"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I am validating some XML against this XSD:

```
  <xs:element name="Composite">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="HeldCurrency" type="mstns:HeldCurrencyType"  nillable="true"/>
        <xs:element name="Component" type="mstns:ComponentType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute  name="Type" type="mstns:compositeType" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>x
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="HeldCurrencyType">
    <xs:attribute  name="CashPerCreationUnit" type="xs:double" />
    <xs:attribute  name="CashCurrency" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute  name="ClosingSpotFx" type="xs:double" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ComponentType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="Weight" type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="Units" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="Symbol" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="compositeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Index" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Etf" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

When I run the following XML against it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Composite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Type="Etf" xmlns="urn:xxx-au:index-types">
  <HeldCurrency />
  <Component />
</Composite>
```

I run this in C#/.Net4.0 with the following code:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("./Xml/Components.xsd"))
{
    using (var schemaReader = new XmlTextReader(fileStream))
    {
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, schemaReader);
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += OnValidationEventHandler;

        using (FileStream infile = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            using(var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(infile,settings))
            {
                var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Composite));
                _composite = (Composite) serialiser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:
The element 'Component' in namespace 'urn:xxx-au:index-types' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'Weight, Units' in namespace.
However, I have minOccurs="0" so why would this be an issue? It is legal for the sequence to contain no ComponentType elements after all, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: minOccurs here is only for the Component element. Once you have that element, the xs:choice part kicks in and requires one of those to be present.

Comment: +1, for certain question! every xsd developer comes across this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xs:element name="Component" type="mstns:ComponentType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

The `minOccurs` here is for specifically the "Component" element -- not its contents. ComponentType has content of `xs:choice`, which does not have a `minOccurs` of `0`. So you can omit "Component" entirely, but not its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Element `Component`'s minOccurs is `0` not it's children elements'..

so try this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="ComponentType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="Weight" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Units" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="Symbol" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

where I have defined occurence of Weight and Units as  '0' also made attribute as optional!

Comment: @JarekMitek, I suggested attribute as well ;)

Comment: btw, are you the guy who appeared in mortal kombat? :D jokes apart, it's all fine to select any answer! the aim is to provide solutions to problems of fellow SO members!!